# If $\alpha=(a_1a_2...a_k)$ is a $k$-cycle, then $\alpha^i(a_j)=a_{(j+i)\text{ mod }k}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, permutations, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to show that if $\alpha=(a_1a_2...a_k)$ is a $k$-cycle, then for all $j\in\{1,2,...,k\}$ and any $i\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $\alpha^i(a_j)=a_{(j+i)\text{ mod }k}$. I was hoping folks could check my proof and perhaps comment on if it's more natural to use simple induction or strong induction.

**Proof**: (strong)

When $i=1$, if $j<k$ then by definition of the cycle $\alpha=(a_1a_2...a_k)$ we have $\alpha(a_j)=a_{(j+1)}=a_{(j+1)\text{ mod }k}$ since $j+1\leq k$ if $j<k$ and $a_{0 \text{ mod } k}= a_{k\text{ mod } k}$. If $j=k$, then again by definition of the cycle $\alpha=(a_1a_2...a_k)$ we have $\alpha(a_j)=\alpha(a_k)=a_1=a_{(k+1)\text{ mod }k}$.

Now assume by induction that for all $i$ less than $k$ and greater than $1$ that $\alpha^i(a_j)=a_{(j+i)\text{ mod }k}$ holds. Let $i=k$. Then $$\alpha^i(a_j)=\alpha^k(a_j)=\alpha(\alpha^{k-1}(a_j))$$ but by the induction hypothesis $\alpha^{k-1}(a_j)=a_{(j+k-1)\text{ mod }k}$ so $$\alpha^i(a_j)=\alpha^k(a_j)=\alpha(\alpha^{k-1}(a_j))=\alpha(a_{(j+k-1)\text{ mod }k}).$$

> Now, since $(j+k-1)\text{ mod }k +1 =(j+k-1)\text{ mod }k+(1)\text{ mod }k=(j+k)\text{ mod }k$ and $(j+k-1)\text{ mod }k\leq k $ we have

again by definition of the cycle $\alpha=(a_1a_2...a_k)$ that:

$$\alpha(a_{(j+k-1)\text{ mod }k})=a_{(j+k)\text{ mod }k}=a_{(j+i)\text{ mod }k}$$
so $\alpha^i(a_j)=a_{(j+i)\text{ mod }k}$. Thus the claim holds for $i=k$, and by induction $\alpha^i(a_j)=a_{(j+i)\text{ mod }k}$ holds for any $k$-cycle where $k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$. $\blacksquare$

**Proof:** (simple)

When $i=1$, if $j<k$ then by definition of the cycle $\alpha=(a_1a_2...a_k)$ we have $\alpha(a_j)=a_{(j+1)}=a_{(j+1)\text{ mod }k}$ since $j+1\leq k$ if $j<k$ and $a_{0 \text{ mod } k}= a_{k\text{ mod } k}$. If $j=k$, then again by definition of the cycle $\alpha=(a_1a_2...a_k)$, we have $\alpha(a_j)=\alpha(a_k)=a_1=a_{(k+1)\text{ mod }k}$.

Now assume by induction that $\alpha^i(a_j)=a_{(j+i)\text{ mod }k}$ holds for some $i\geq1$. Then by the induction hypothesis: $$\alpha^{i+1}(a_j)=\alpha(\alpha^i(a_j))=\alpha(a_{(j+i)\text{ mod }k})$$

> so by definition of the cycle $\alpha=(a_1a_2...a_k)$ and that $(j+i)\text{ mod }k\leq k$ we have

$$\alpha(a_{(j+i)\text{ mod }k})=a_{(j+i+1)\text{ mod }k}.$$

Hence the claim holds for all $j$ in $\{1,2,...k\}$ and for all natural numbers $i$ by induction. $\blacksquare$

Are there any gaps, specifically in the induction step(s) highlighted? I'm concerned I'm not properly accounting for the cases when the element is the last in the cycle $(=k)$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For $k$ even, take $i=j=k/2$. Then the RHS of your formula yields "$a_0$", which is what?

Comment: @Devo Here I am taking $a_{0\pmod k}=a_{k\pmod k}$.

Comment: (1) Your strong induction isn't actually strong induction.  It's just simple induction with extra baggage.  I'd advise you to get rid of the strong induction altogether (if you really want to keep it, you need to use a different letter for the $k$ appearing in the inductive hypothesis).  ... (2) Both your inductive hypotheses are disconnected from your base case, so if you only fixed the notational issues, neither induction would "work".  You need to include $i=1$ as a possibility.  For instance, since I believe you should only keep the simple induction, you should remove the $>1$ from $i>1$.

Comment: What is the context of this question, OP? What are you allowed to use?

Comment: @Mike I'm just trying to use this result to prove that the order of a $k$ cycle is $k$. I can use pretty much whatever within group theory and induction/gcd type stuff.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you! I agree I felt myself that the strong induction argument I gave was really just simple induction. So I will use simple induction as you recommended. But now that I do that, I don't still have to change the notation around do I? I can just delete the $>1$ part so that the base case is included in the induction hypothesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your main focus (expressed in a comment), let's start from the definition of $k$-cycle:

$\alpha(a_i)=a_{i+1}$, for $i=1,\dots,k-1$

$\alpha(a_k)=a_1$

---

Step to get insight on the formula to be proven by induction:

$\alpha^2(a_i)=\alpha(a_{i+1})=a_{i+2}$, for $i=1,\dots,k-2$

$\alpha^2(a_{k-1})=\alpha(\alpha(a_{k-1}))=\alpha(a_k)=a_1$

$\alpha^2(a_{k})=\alpha(\alpha(a_{k}))=\alpha(a_1)=a_2$

So, the proper definition of the $j$-th power of $\alpha$, $1\le j\le k$, relies on the splitting of the set $\{1,\dots, k\}$ into $\{1,\dots, k-j\}$ and $\{k-j+1,\dots, k\}$, which must be part of the induction process.

---

**Induction**:

Inductive hypothesis ("i.h."):

1. $\alpha^j(a_i)=a_{i+j}$, for $i=1,\dots,k-j$
2. $\alpha^j(a_{k-j+l})=a_l$, for $l=1,\dots,j$

For $j=1$ we retrieve the definition of $k$-cycle. Now the case $j+1$:

- for $i=1,\dots,k-(j+1)$, we get: $\alpha^{j+1}(a_i)=$ $\alpha(\alpha^j(a_i))\stackrel{(i.h.)}{=}$ $\alpha(a_{i+j})\stackrel{(j+1\le i+j\le k-1)}{=}a_{i+(j+1)}$;
- for $l=1,\dots,j+1$, we get: $\alpha^{j+1}(a_{k-(j+1)+l})=$ $\alpha(\alpha^j(a_{k-(j+1)+l}))=$ $\alpha(\alpha^j(a_{k-j+(l-1)}))$; now:

  - for $l=1$, we get: $\alpha(\alpha^j(a_{k-j+(l-1)}))=$ $\alpha(\alpha^j(a_{k-j}))\stackrel{(i.h.,\text{ part 1})}{=}$ $\alpha(a_k)=a_1$;
  - for $l=2,\dots,j+1$, we get: $\alpha(\alpha^j(a_{k-j+(l-1)}))\stackrel{(i.h.,\text{ part 2})}{=}$ $\alpha(a_{l-1})=$ $a_l$,

  and hence $\alpha^{j+1}(a_{k-(j+1)+l})=a_l$ for every $l=1,\dots,j+1$. $\space\Box$

---

For $j<k$, from the part 1 follows $\alpha^j(a_1)=a_{j+1}\ne a_1$, and hence $\alpha^j\ne Id$.

On the other hand, for $j=k$, part 2 tells the whole story, which is: $\alpha^k(a_l)=a_l$, for $l=1,\dots,k$, namely $\alpha^k=Id$.

Therefore, $\left|\alpha\right|=k$.